# Anylogic: Setting Scale Programmatically

Tags: anylogic

I want to run a series of experiments in anylogic by scaling my warehouse up and down to see the effects of increasing or decreasing floor space. I think the simplest way to do this would be to play with the scale. However, I can't figure out how to set the scale programmatically. Since I have multiple designs that I want to scale up and down, it would be much more efficient if I can do this programmatically as opposed to doing this manually.

Comment: why not dynamically change the actual animation element (rectangle for floor space, using its 'setWidth()` method for example)

Comment: What is your warehouse modeled as? The answer to this question will impact the answer to your question... Is it just 2D presentation shapes (e.g. rectangle) in main? Is it an agent? Does it include walls? Racks? etc.

Comment: It includes walls, shapes and pedestrian agents. I am open to some clever alternatives. Playing with the scale is the only way I could think of but maybe there are better ways of doing the same analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot change the scale of agents dynamically you can easily change them during setup on the animation presentation of the agent.

See the example below. If you select "Scale is" as "Defined Explicitly" you can change the scale.

[image]

This is the best you can do, AFAIK

Comment: I also have walls in my simulation and I am not sure if this approach will work the same for walls. Essentially I want everything in the animation to scale by a factor.

Comment: I am not sure about the pedestrain objects.. but test it and let us know... I do not think your approach will work.. perhaps consider drawing items programmatically.. then you can control the scaling 100% - but I also don't know if you can draw the pedestrain walls programmatically.

Comment: I can draw the walls programmatically however I don't think they have a scaling option. The only option remaining I feel is to manually play with the scale to scale up (1m = 50px to 1m=45px) and down(1m = 50px to 1m=55px).

Comment: Ok, looking forward to your feedback but I am sure my solution would suffice. Let me know.